# hiding the cursor in a full screen java application on the Mac using webstart

Tags: java, macos, java-web-start

I have a fullscreen Java application in which I need to hide the cursor on a Mac.
I've created the transparent cursor as instructed here and elsewhere, which works
fine on Windows. It does not work on the Mac. I've tried a both a system command
and a native command to get ride of it, but that only works when I run it locally
on my own computer. When I compile it and upload it to a server using webstart,
then download it and run it, it no long works.

I've attempted simply changing the cursor to one of the default cursers, and that
does not work on startup either. Both the invisible cursor and default cursor do
work once I move the cursor up to the top of the screen, but I need it to be
invisible immediately. I have setUndercorated set to true.

I've searched everywhere and found answers that work on windows, or that work when
I run locally on my Mac, but nothing that works when the application is downloaded
and run on any Mac.

Comment: Any luck with [`System.setProperty("apple.awt.fullscreenhidecursor", "true")`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Reference/Java_PropertiesRef/Articles/JavaSystemProperties.html)?

Comment: Thanks trashgod. Using that system command works locally, but not when downloaded from the web.